# Preload cached credentials Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Does anybody know if there is some way in Windows 10 to preload a users cached credentials on a domain joined computer?
The problem is that computers needs to be shipped to users that may not be on corporate network when they start the computer for the first time.
I found some threads from a couple of years back with some tricks to copy user hives etc in the registry but for that fix we need to pull the credentials from another machine the user has already been logged in to and that is not always the case.
Since the answers I find is a couple of years old I am giving it a shot that somebody has come up with a solution to this or that functionality that I am not aware of exists in the Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is Azure AD.

Comment: Azure AD is not an option for us